# Aws ios multipart upload

Tags: ios, file-upload, amazon-web-services, multipart

I wanted to upload large audio file on aws bucket.
how can I achieve this using multi - part upload functionality in s3 ?
link to any tutorial will help.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the iOS SDK: 
http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/

Here is the documentation, which you  may have seen:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's [AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/) claims to be able to "Store and retrieve any amount of data using Amazon S3." I've not tried it myself, but downloading the SDK and playing with the sample files would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: I read the documentation and couldn't find a way to give a file path in it.